# CentOSで複数ファイル内文字列の一括置換をしたいのですが、うまくいきません…

Tags: bash

**置換前**
・hoge.jp/stackoverflow

---

**置換後**
・piyo/hoge.jp

---

**試したけれどもうまくいかなかったコード**

```
find /path -type f | xargs sed -i 's/hoge.jp%stackoverflow/piyo&hoge.jp/g'
```

・意味は良く分かっていません
・区切りに/が入るとエラーになるとネットに書いてあってので、%で区切っています

---

**質問**
・何がマズいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /path -type f | xargs sed -i 's%hoge\.jp/stackoverflow%piyo/hoge.jp%g'
```

とします。

---

```
sed -i 's/hoge.jp%stackoverflow/piyo&hoge.jp/g'
```

この様に書いてしまいますと、以下の変換を行います。

```
hoge.jp%stackoverflow  =>  piyo&hoge.jp
```

sed の `s` コマンドでは、`s` の次の文字がセパレータとして認識されます。このセパレータ文字は `s` コマンドに指定する正規表現文字列と変換先文字列に含まれない文字であれば使用可能です。ですので、以下は全て同じ変換になります。

```
s%hoge\.jp/stackoverflow%piyo/hoge.jp%g  ## %
s@hoge\.jp/stackoverflow@piyo/hoge.jp@g  ## @
s:hoge\.jp/stackoverflow:piyo/hoge.jp:g  ## :
s_hoge\.jp/stackoverflow_piyo/hoge.jp_g  ## _
sZhoge\.jp/stackoverflowZpiyo/hoge.jpZg  ## Z
```

なお、`.` が任意の一文字にマッチする正規表現なので `\` でエスケープします(`hoge.jp/stackoverflow` 内の `.` のみ)。

Comment: 本文中に現れにくい文字として、制御コードENQ(0x05)を区切り文字に使うことがよくあります。

Answer (score 1):

`sed` のコマンドライン引数についてはすでに付いてる回答にある通りですが、より完全で、より効率的なコマンドラインをどうぞ。

```
$ find /path -type f -exec sed -i 's%hoge\.jp/stackoverflow%piyo/hoge.jp%g' {} +
```

完全→`find` が見つけたパスに空白文字などが含まれていても大丈夫、効率的→`sed` の起動回数を必要最小限に抑えることができる。`xargs` も不要。

詳細は `find`(1) のオンラインマニュアルをどうぞ。

`find` の `-exec` あるいは `find` と `xargs` の組合せは「意味は良く分かっていません」な状態で利用するのは危険ですよ。

Comment: 「空白文字などが含まれていても大丈夫」なのは何故でしょうか？「-exec command {} +」の説明を読んでみたのですが、よく分かりませんでした…

Comment: `xargs` は、デフォルトでは入力内容を色々解釈します。例えば、空白文字で分割したものを指定したコマンドに渡します。`foo bar` というファイルが存在した場合、`sed` には `foo` と `bar` が渡されます。ほかにバックスラッシュ `\` を特別扱いします。詳細はマニュアルをどうぞ。`xargs` のそういった処理が不要な場合、`find` との組合せでは `find` の -print0 オプションと、`xargs` の `-0` (`--null`) オプションを利用するのが通例です。

ただし、今回の場合は `xargs` は不要で、例示したように `find` だけで実現可能です。`find` は `-exec` に指定したコマンドラインに発見したファイル名をそのまま渡すので、`xargs` (のデフォルト動作)のような問題は発生しません。

Comment: なるほど。同じ結果を得るにしても色々なやり方があるわけですね。出来るだけ効率良いやり方で作業したいと思っているので、大変参考になりました

Comment: 「find /path -type f -exec sed」だとfindで見つかったファイル数だけsedが起動されるため、xargsを使った方が生成されるプロセス数は少なくなると思います。

Comment: @akira ejiri `-exec`の最後が`+`になっているのが肝で、できるだけ多くの引数を`sed`に渡しています。

Comment: manマニュアルを調べてみました。-exec command {} + の + は知りませんでした。全ファイルを候補とするとき、プロセス数が爆発的に増えるので、これまでfind の execを使うのを控えていました。認識が改まりました。伽語蓮弥さん、ご指摘どうもありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

## sed -iの問題

`sed -i`は置換されない場合もファイルのタイムスタンプが更新されてしまいます。
`ex`コマンドを使って`x`で終了すると置換されていないファイルのタイムスタンプは更新されません。

## 今回紹介するスクリプト(exコマンドを使用)

```
#!/bin/bash
case $# in
0|1|2)cat <<EOF 1>&2
Usage: chp re string files...
EOF
exit 1
esac
DLMT=$(echo -n -e "\x05")
re=$1
str=$2
shift 2

for file in $@
do
ex -s ${file} <<EOF
:%s${DLMT}${re}${DLMT}${str}${DLMT}g
x
EOF
done
```

## 実行例

```
find /path -type f | xargs bash 【今回紹介したスクリプト】△hoge\\.jp△stackoverflow△piyo/hoge.jp
```

△は空白です。
※`.`をエスケープするには`\`を２回指定しなければならないのが難です。